# Display confirmation between two servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I have a servlet called `Delete_product_Kind_A`.

When user delete any product of kind A, the servlet will be called and it will looks for the product of kind A in database.

A user comfirm to delete products should be display. If user choose "YES", it will fire a request on another servlet `Action_Delete`.

So, please tell me, how can I display confirmation between two serlvet?

I have found on internet and found a code like this:

```
out.println("<script>");
out.println("confirm('somethings')");
out.println("</script>");
```

But I don't know how to get its value to check yes or no. 
Thanks so much.

Answer (score -1):

Just use `if` statement and fire and ajax call to the second servlet:

```
if(confirm('something?')) {
    alert('YES clicked!');
    // perform here the ajax call to Action_delete servlet
} else {
    alert('Cancel clicked!');
}
```

Comment: I still don't understand your answer. In this case, I call a servlet A and it will check in server and the confirm is in client. So how can I get it value?
Should I create another jsp file?

Comment: @nptn like you said since the confirmation is client side you have to handle it in the same place, so in order to call the second servlet you have to perform "something" to check/fire the request by js. Just replace the js in the `out.println` and you will be able to see the user choice in a new alert. Then you have to create your ajax request for the Action_delete servlet.

Answer (score -1):

Best way is to use a controller class or use a controller design pattern

```
[controller design pattern][1]
```

as you require authentication before deleting and also working with 2 servlets